# Distributive Conditional Types as Recursive Types

Tags: typescript, generics

I made `Shape` type, where the `ShapeConfig` is recursive. As we can see in `Combined` shape.
The thing is, I want to `ExtractShape` from `Combined` shape to be specific, not as union.
Just by using `ShapeConfig<Shape>`, we don't get what we want (`let typeNonDist: Shape`).
Then I tried to use [Distributive Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).
It worked, only for non-recursive type (`let typeNonRecur: "Square"`).
When I apply it to `Combined` child (`asDist["child"][0]`), typescript inferred it's type as `let typeDist: "Triangle" | "Square" | "Combined"`.
But, when I use `as const`, It worked  (`let typeConst: "Square"`).
Is there any way to infer like `asConst`, while using `asDist` type? Because I don't want to build shape with `DistShapeConfig<Shape>`, just to change it to `as const` to infer it's type.

```js
    type Shape = "Triangle" | "Square" | "Combined"

    type ShapeConfig<T extends Shape> = {
        kind: T
    } & (
        T extends "Triangle" | "Square" ? {
            sideLength: number
        } :
        T extends "Combined" ? {
            child: DistShapeConfig<Shape>[]
        } : 
        never
    )

    type DistShapeConfig<T extends Shape> = T extends any ? ShapeConfig<T> : never

    type ExtractShape<T> = T extends { kind: infer R } ? R : never

    // Without Distributive Conditional Types
    const nonDist: ShapeConfig<Shape> = {
      kind: "Square",
      sideLength: 2
    }
    let typeNonDist: ExtractShape<typeof nonDist>

    // Without recursion
    const nonRecur:DistShapeConfig<Shape> = {
      kind: "Square",
      sideLength: 2
    }
    let typeNonRecur: ExtractShape<typeof nonRecur>

    // With Distributive Conditional Types and Recursion 
    const asDist: DistShapeConfig<Shape> = {
        kind: "Combined",
        child: [
            {
                kind: "Square",
                sideLength: 2
            },
            {
                kind: "Triangle",
                sideLength: 3
            }
        ]
    }

    let typeDist: ExtractShape<typeof asDist["child"][0]>

    // With const
    const asConst = {
        kind: "Combined",
        child: [
            {
                kind: "Square",
                sideLength: 2
            },
            {
                kind: "Triangle",
                sideLength: 3
            }
        ]
    } as const

    let typeConst: ExtractShape<typeof asConst["child"][0]>
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2BlAFgQ1sAvMARAFQE4CWyAdgOYA2MWwAPtvAI4CuyeVt2AwgPYC2ARgWIwAJlgCwAKCmhw0OElQwexAGYFSAHhzAYADzAxiIgM4IUsAHwZgAbxmzQAayEiAXMBwOQAX2AAyYAAKb0cdfUNjM1xCEgp2OixGFjZqAH47UMdQEwIRGAAZI1IwRA9iJgEYPCzQPzdakHCDI1MuPkFhMWAM+0ls7IBjRAJyd2AAEQITMEVYFXUtOZhLAG0AXUbgeuAt4QA3atCASilQyDQpmeWFjW1dFqjzJWtMZsi2kgge5-nuNTuOGs5Rghxq0n6oAucAAogY8MhBrMLDBtK9PA8PmZbMAXMYPEJVNVgAAlbY-MkgsFnSEgAD0dOAAHUCKVuEwwJNpmBCPwOQRDsAVCJWQR-shyJ55CZQoN-jNgMR-lcwB4bv9Fpplui+tk8eMksxWFQADS1XL5IpkUoeABMoR8oUonOhADlldyPHCeYjkUpNNDuKpFR6ZpYabIGczWYh2Zy2IMmHhcv9ZfLOUriCSYIm8G4VeqAUsUTravqPIaUqbzXlCsUbcB7bTtk6YC75O6szmk174b7lgH5EGQ13c+GIZHGSzSlyZrz+YLhaLxZKcNLgCQRKTu8mxcRds25cQFcgTCqPAWUbdiy8bLqBuX2gIhKIsGbm7JhqNxqstrJ7wMD6uBWyTGm+f4DBadbWmUjYQb476Af+8GOI+MREGQlDgR+SEgFBVolLBADMKGOjhICbM2ZGtu2sDnsA3oIkiA6BsGp4qqsWBfmMWDrKsAAM6zjqEUbTogwBHjMabHpyp4qAqmAAahwFPp0r6IQM3E-ihSm4SAaGgakGl6TktYEQ2TYmT4xlIbpelofgGHxNhJmyPh9bEaRWyUbIfinhJ6YRqAzpyH8Mm9j6zEooOsDDnJ6acVpvECUJNJSEAA)

Comment: Reading through this code, I don't think your issue has to do with recursion or with conditional types; instead, it's about type inference and narrowing; the same problem occurs [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NdErXm); if a variable is annotated with a union type, then assignment will narrow it.  If a variable is annotated with a non-union type, then assignment will not narrow it.  If a variable is not annotated at all, and you use a `const` assertion on the initializer, then it will get a much narrower type inferred.

Comment: This is all intended behavior of TS.  You seem to want another option, but I'm not sure what it would be.  Maybe the new [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) would help?  Like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N75oDW)?   So you get the narrowing of `as const` but it's still checked against your type (without annotating it and widening it)

Comment: Let me know if you want an answer written up that says this (and suggests `satisfies`) or if I'm missing something about the question.

Comment: When I tried to use it only with one child in `Combined` type, it infer it's type perfectly as I expected. Until I introduce more of it. It's start to becoming union again
[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wo8Apw)

Comment: Anyway, just tested it with both `satisfies` and `as const`. It infer it's type even when I add more child, and still being annotated. I need to add `readonly` in `Combined` type, so It won't give me error about mutable array type. [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBJ5DN). I think you can start write the answer for this. @jcalz